# Как отфильтровать по размеру группы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, анализ-данных

Дан `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}])
```

Как можно оставить только те id, которых имеется в количестве 7 штук. То есть, на выходе мы должны получить:

```
        pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 0}])
```

Методом тыка, пользуясь ответами на мои предыдущие вопросы, пришел вот к такому решению:

```
a.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: (x['id'].size==7))
```

Но до конца не уверен, верно ли это. Возможно есть более правильное и быстрое решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение, использующее метод “.filter()” наиболее идиоматичное для такого рода проверок. Можно его чуточку сократить, но по сути это то же решение:

```
a.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 7)
```